# Adding rows dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm building a form where I need multiple optional inputs, what I have is basically this:

[image: form example]

Every time a user presses the plus button a new row of form inputs should be added to the form, how can I do this in jQuery? **Also, is it possible to automatically add a new row when all rows** (or just the last row, if it's easier / faster) **are filled?** That way the user wouldn't need to press the plus button.

I'm sorry for asking maybe such a basic question but I'm still very green with jQuery, I could do this with PHP but I'm sure Javascript / jQuery plays a more appropriate role here.

---

### @alex:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$form = $('#personas');
$rows = $form.find('.person');

$('a#add').click(function() {
    $rows.find(':first').clone().insertAfter($rows.find(':last'));
    $justInserted = $rows.find(':last');
    $justInserted.hide();
    $justInserted.find('input').val(''); // it may copy values from first one
    $justInserted.slideDown(500);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="personas" name="personas" method="post" action="">
  <table width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>More?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="person">
      <td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name[]" /></td>
      <td><a href="#" id="add">+</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Rippo: Tried it and it doesn't work. Isn't the `$form.find('.person')` supposed to find all elements that have the `person` class inside the form with `personas` id?

Comment: Why use the selector a#add instead of just #add?

Comment: @chris: I realize that, I was just trying not to change @alex logic.

Comment: @Alix Axel  - did u get this working ?? because i am searching for something similar.

Comment: @pradeep: Yup, I wouldn't have accepted the answer otherwise.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This will get you close, the add button has been removed out of the table so you might want to consider this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#add").click(function() {
          $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
          return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML markup looks like this

```
  <a  id="add">+</a></td>
  <table id="mytable" width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="person">
      <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**EDIT** To empty a value of a textbox after insert..

```
    $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
    $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #name').val('');
    return false;
```

**EDIT2** Couldn't help myself, to reset all dropdown lists in the inserted TR you can do this

```
$("#mytable tbody>tr:last").each(function() {this.reset();});
```

I will leave the rest to you!

Comment: That works fine, thanks. Now, is there any way to reset all inputs / selects / textareas / etc to their original state in the newly created row?

Comment: The only thing I would say is that it should be name="something[]" and there should be no id, as ids should be unique.

Comment: Very nice solution, worked great for me.  I made mine fade in by adding the following after the "insertAfter()" but before the semicolon: .hide().fadeIn(500)

Comment: I also made the plus buttons disappear by having them be a class rather than an id="", and then using this code before the return false: $('.add').hide();

Comment: Also, your HTML snippet doesn't include the "add" button.  This assumes you are using ".add" rather than "#add", but here is what I used:  <td><img src="add.png" class="add" alt="+"></img></td>

Comment: I think it might make more sense to just establish a default row outside the main table and clone that as needed. This would make "resetting" individual defaults for each field a lot easier, yes? Otherwise, great answer. Thanks! Kickedstarted my handy little plugin.

Comment: I just wanted to say  that on Feb 4, 2018, this answer was still helpful to me. Thanks for providing a great, clear, detailed answer with examples.

Answer (score 7):

As an addition to answers above: you probably might need to change ids in names/ids of input elements (pls note, you should not have digits in fields name):

```
<input name="someStuff.entry[2].fieldOne" id="someStuff_fdf_fieldOne_2" ..>
```

I have done this having some global variable by default set to 0:

```
var globalNewIndex = 0;
```

and in the add function after you've cloned and resetted the values in the new row:

```
                var newIndex = globalNewIndex+1;
                var changeIds = function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(globalNewIndex,newIndex);
                }
                $('#mytable tbody>tr:last input').attr('name', changeIds ).attr('id', changeIds );
                globalNewIndex++;
```

Answer (score 4):

I have Tried something like this and its works fine;

[image]

this is the html part :

```
<table class="dd" width="100%" id="data">
<tr>
<td>Year</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><select name="year1" id="year1" >
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
</select></td>
<td>Month</td>
<td>:</td>
<td width="17%"><select name="month1" id="month1">
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select></td>
<td width="7%">Week</td>
<td width="3%">:</td>
<td width="17%"><select name="week1" id="week1" >
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select></td>
<td width="8%">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Actual</td>
<td>:</td>
<td width="17%"><input name="actual1" id="actual1" type="text" /></td>
<td width="7%">Max</td>
<td width="3%">:</td>
<td><input name="max1" id="max1" type="text" /></td>
<td>Target</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="target1" id="target1" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
```

this is Javascript part;

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
var currentItem = 1;
$('#addnew').click(function(){
currentItem++;
$('#items').val(currentItem);
var strToAdd = '<tr><td>Year</td><td>:</td><td><select name="year'+currentItem+'" id="year'+currentItem+'" ><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2011">2011</option></select></td><td>Month</td><td>:</td><td width="17%"><select name="month'+currentItem+'" id="month'+currentItem+'"><option value="1">January</option><option value="2">February</option><option value="3">March</option><option value="4">April</option><option value="5">May</option><option value="6">June</option><option value="7">July</option><option value="8">August</option><option value="9">September</option><option value="10">October</option><option value="11">November</option><option value="12">December</option></select></td><td width="7%">Week</td><td width="3%">:</td><td width="17%"><select name="week'+currentItem+'" id="week'+currentItem+'" ><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option></select></td><td width="8%"></td><td colspan="2"></td></tr><tr><td>Actual</td><td>:</td><td width="17%"><input name="actual'+currentItem+'" id="actual'+currentItem+'" type="text" /></td><td width="7%">Max</td> <td width="3%">:</td><td><input name="max'+currentItem+'" id ="max'+currentItem+'"type="text" /></td><td>Target</td><td>:</td><td><input name="target'+currentItem+'" id="target'+currentItem+'" type="text" /></td></tr>';
  $('#data').append(strToAdd);

 });
 });

 //]]>
 </script>
```

Finaly PHP submit part:

```
    for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ )
{
    $year = $_POST['year'.$i];
    $month = $_POST['month'.$i];
    $week = $_POST['week'.$i];
    $actual = $_POST['actual'.$i];
    $max = $_POST['max'.$i];
    $target = $_POST['target'.$i];
    $extreme = $_POST['extreme'.$i];
    $que = "insert INTO table_name(id,year,month,week,actual,max,target) VALUES ('".$_POST['type']."','".$year."','".$month."','".$week."','".$actual."','".$max."','".$target."')";
    mysql_query($que);

}
```

you can find more details via [Dynamic table row inserter](https://www.iranthajayasekara.com/blog/jquery-dynamic-table-row-inserter.html)

Comment: Be careful about using the PHP part as its open to SQL injection (I think)

Answer (score 3):

Untested.
Modify to suit:

```
$form = $('#my-form');

$rows = $form.find('.person-input-row');

$('button#add-new').click(function() {

    $rows.find(':first').clone().insertAfter($rows.find(':last'));

    $justInserted = $rows.find(':last');
    $justInserted.hide();
    $justInserted.find('input').val(''); // it may copy values from first one
    $justInserted.slideDown(500);


});
```

This is better than copying innerHTML because you will lose all attached events etc.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense but I still can't get it to work, check my edited question.

Comment: This will clone what is inside the tr, in this case the td's and insert td's after the last one. close but not quite right.

Comment: It was alright up until the edit :) Sorry, I went out after posting and didn't have a chance to make edits.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the other answers, I simplified things a bit. By cloning the last element, we get the "add new" button for free (you have to change the ID to a class because of the cloning) and also reduce DOM operations. I had to use filter() instead of find() to get only the last element.

```
$('.js-addNew').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var $rows   = $('.person'),
       $last   = $rows.filter(':last'),
       $newRow = $last.clone().insertAfter($last);

   $last.find($('.js-addNew')).remove(); // remove old button
   $newRow.hide().find('input').val('');
   $newRow.slideDown(500);
});
```

Comment: This works, but because the button on any new rows didn't exist at the time the event handler was registered, you need to do so again.