# How to insert data into table

Tags: html, frontpage

I need to know how to insert data into table. For example (Table - students info) :

```
No | Student Name | Address | Phone Number

1. |    Add       |         |
```

Add - is a hyperlink. The user need to click Add(hyperlink) to add student. After the user click Add, then this page will be display :

```
Student : <textbox>
Address : <textbox>
Phone Number : <dropdownlist> <textbox>

Submit<submit button>
```

Then, the user will click Submit button and the data that the user enter will be display in the table. Like this :

```
No | Student Name | Address | Phone Number
1. | Patrick      | Malaysia| 013366666
2. |    Add       |         |
```

I'm using Microsoft FrontPage 2003. Thank You.

Comment: Have a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145012/adding-rows-dynamically-with-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145012/adding-rows-dynamically-with-jquery).

Comment: @neo108: jQuery with Frontpage? =)

Comment: Sorry. I was meant to say that jQuery/javascript can be used to achieve this.

Comment: You should take this as just a comment.. but the technology you are using is pretty ancient. If you are developing something new, keeping maintainability and ease of use in mind... frontpage might not be a good option anymore. Many (even free) tools available today allow you to do this without coding a single letter.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds to me like you are wanting to perform 3 functions. 1.) functionality to add to the list. (the add link.) 2.) to build a form to input the data for the list. 3.) to print the list out. (or echo the list in a table).

You mentioned that your using frontpage, however some more information would be great in order to better assist you. For example, what server technologies do you have available? (php, database type?, cgi, asp, etc.) or is your add functionality going to add the data to a flat file? (.txt, etc.) usually only used for storing the data locally. If you are unsure which server technologies you have available (if any), you can ask your web server administrator, isp, or web hosting provider.

I know I should avoid statements based on opinion.. However, probably the best way to get a very good output would be to use php and a database server to conduct all of this. I say this because, if you use a database server as opposed to a flat file, you can "echo" the data with some organization, instead of the organization just being what student information was entered first. With the database technology, you could organize it with the country they are from, or by the first or last name, etc. Making it so that if the list gets really long you aren't hunting for the students information you are looking for, or needing to use the find functionality in your browser or other program you might use with this. just a little insight to help you avoid future headaches. :)

Ok so if you can give use some of that information, it might help us help you a lot easier!

oh, and here is a link about what Microsoft has to say about collecting and storing form data entered by site users: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/frontpage-help/collect-and-store-form-data-entered-by-site-visitors-HP005261723.aspx

Hope you find this helpful, or at least somewhat informative. Sorry I couldn't help you further without knowing more information about what server technologies you have available. However, if you get that information to us I am sure that we can assist you a lot "better".