# Jquery Dynamically add new row fields

Tags: jquery, mysql

Hi i want to add multiple rows dynamically of my form with same fields but different form field name (e.g. city1, city2, city3,... college1,college2,college3...) and then all data into mysql

I tried so my search but nothing works for me here is my code please help me in this

```
<div class="form_student_add">
                    <table class="dd" width="100%" id="data">
                    <tr>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td>College</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <select name="city" id="city">
                    <option selected="selected" value="0">--Select City--</option>
                    <?php                           
                        $sql=mysql_query("select * from tblcities");
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                                {
                                    $id=$row['city_id'];
                                    $data=$row['city_name'];
                                    echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
                                } 
                    ?>
                    </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                    <select name="college" id="college">
                    <option selected="selected" value="0">--Select College--</option>
                    <?php                           
                        $sql=mysql_query("select * from tblcollege");
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                                {
                                    $id=$row['college_id'];
                                    $data=$row['college_name'];
                                    echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
                                } 
                    ?>
                    </select></td>

                    <td><input name="full_name" type="text" placeholder="e.g. John Smith" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table> 

                    <div class="form_btn_videos">
                    <input type="button" id="id="addTableRow"" name="addnew" value="Add New Part" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: "but nothing works" is not a valid problem description. Tell us what this code produces, and what you expect that it produces.

Comment: I followed these instructions available on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145012/adding-rows-dynamically-with-jquery

but Iam only able to add more filed but js dont load the php populated drop downs as you can see i have 3 drop downss so I am only able to create a html coded drop down but i want to populate drop down through mysql please check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/13741715/3606257