# Clone a fragment on HTML - Best practices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I'm trying to clone a section on a HTML page on user click. 
In a form, I'm trying to copy and add a field group, when user wants to add more elements to the form.

While cloning, I want to make sure all the ids are rewritten so that the page and elements are intact.
I've been thinking about a neat way of doing this.

Trying the following approaches. 
Am more in favour of JQuery because of the compactness and beauty in the expression. 
Would love to hear some perspectives from experts.

**JS Approach:**

```
function addElementToParentById(src) {

var temp = document.getElementById(src);
var tempParent = temp.parentElement;
var tempNew = temp.cloneNode(true);
renameIds(tempNew,"1");
tempParent.appendChild(tempNew);

}

function renameIds(param, token) {

if(param.id){
    param.id=param.id+token;
}

for(i =0; i < param.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var tempChild = param.childNodes[i];
    if(tempChild.id) {
        tempChild.id = tempChild.id + token;
    }

    if(tempChild.childNodes 
            && tempChild.childNodes.length > 0) {
        for(j =0; j < param.childNodes.length; j++) {
            renameIds(tempChild.childNodes[j], token);
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Jquery approach:**

```
$("#addbtnid").click( function() {
                        $("#filopsmainpane").append($("#filopspane").clone(false).find("*[id]").andSelf().each(
                            function() { $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "1"); }));
                    }
```

Comment: There is no best practice as it all depends on the circumstances. For starters, you wouldn't add jQuery just for the sole purpose of cloning some HTML fragment.

Comment: My question was more on what's a neat way to clone HTML fragments on a form in the similar lines as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145012/adding-rows-dynamically-with-jquery).

Comment: A small snippet of what I started off doing is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nav064/exo2796L/5/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Best" is subjective, but I prefer using a framework (for example jQuery) because:

- Shorter code is less likely to contain an error and is easier to maintain
- The framework's authors have already done the work to deal with browser inconsistencies

Comment: I agree. jQuery and even [knockoutjs] (http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/tfflt/) seem to do some cool stuff here.