# Django form with dynamic (user-selected) field quantity

Tags: python, django, django-forms

My goal is to have a form containing an arbitrary number of records, each containing 3 values. The user should be able to add as many of these records as they need within a single form. For example, see the wireframe in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145012/adding-rows-dynamically-with-jquery)

I'd need it to be backed by something that I can parse back into the DOM if the user wants to edit the data, so a Postgres JSONField may be a good fit.

I know how this could be achieved from scratch, but does Django support this out-of-the-box? Or is there any existing library which would solve this faster?